# Maximum Likelihood of a sum of products - any way to transform?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, posterior, likelihood

I have a likelihood function in this form:

$$L(\lambda) = \sum_i \prod_j f(i,j, \lambda)$$

$f(i,j, \lambda)$ are probabilities, so that their product gets very small. If I try and calculate it in python, it's giving wrong answers due to machine errors.

If it wasn't for the summand I would take the log-likelihood, but I'm not sure what to do. Is there a way to transform this likelihood to make it easier to compute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to compute the log likelihood, avoiding numerical under/overflow by working with log probabilities and using the [log-sum-exp trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp#log-sum-exp_trick_for_log-domain_calculations).

Let $p_i(\lambda)$ be the product of the probabilities over $j$, given $i$ and $\lambda$:

$$p_i(\lambda) = \prod_j f(i,j,\lambda)$$

Obviously, the log can be computed as:

$$\log p_i(\lambda) = \sum_j \log f(i,j,\lambda)$$

Unlike computing the product of many small values, computing the sum of their logs has little danger of underflow. Now, let $v^*(\lambda)$ be the maximal value of $\log p_i(\lambda)$ over all $i$:

$$v^*_\lambda = \max_i \log p_i(\lambda)$$

Using the log-sum-exp trick, the log likelihood can be computed as:

$$\log L(\lambda) =
v^*(\lambda)
+ \log \sum_i \exp \Big(
  \log p_i(\lambda)
  - v^*(\lambda)
\Big)$$

Subtracting $v^*(\lambda)$ inside the exponential terms has the effect of bringing all values into a small range near zero, reducing the risk of under/overflow when we exponentiate. Many numerical computing libraries have a `logsumexp()` function for handling this computation in a numerically safe way (e.g. see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.logsumexp.html) for python).